# Running Build-Heap Algorithm on given numbers

Tags: algorithms, arrays, heaps

I don't fully understand this build-heap function. Lets assume we have array 3, 4, 5, 13, 16, 32.

It seems like we swap the parent when it is less than the current A[j] but which number does the loop start with? Maybe somebody can go through 2-3 loops and show how the array changes after 1st loop, 2nd loop, 3rd loop. Much appreciated. Oh, also, what would be the runtime?

```
for i=2 to n
    j = i
    while (j>1) and A[parent(j)]<A[j] do
        swap A(parent(j)] and A[j]
        j = parent(j)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're building a max-heap, where every element is greater than or equal to its child elements (if any). With that understanding, let's trace the action. First, the parent node of $A[j]$ will be $A[j/2]$ (integer division: discard any remainder) so we'll have
$$\begin{array}{r|cccccccc}
j & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \dotsc\\
parent(j) & \_ & 1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 & 3 & \dotsc
\end{array}$$
To keep things simple, we'll let the initial array be $[3,4,5,13]$:

**Insert at $i=2$**.

$A[parent(2)]=A[1]=3 < 4=A[2]$ so we swap $A[1]$ and $A[2]$, giving us the array
$$
[4,3,5,13]
$$

**Insert at $i=3$**.

$A[parent(3)]=A[1]=4 < 5=A[3]$ so we swap $A[1]$ and $A[3]$, giving us the array
$$
[5,3,4,13]
$$

**Insert at $i=4$**.

$A[parent(4)]=A[2]=3 < 13=A[4]$ so we swap $A[2]$ and $A[3]$, giving us the array
$$
[5,13,4,3]
$$
and now $j=parent(4)=2>1$ so we see if we need another swap.

$A[parent(2)]=A[1]=5 < 13=A[2]$ so we swap $A[1]$ and $A[2]$, giving us the array
$$
[13,5,4,3]
$$
and we're done, the array is now a max-heap.

---

The runtime of this algorithm is no worse than a multiple of $n\log n$ since none of the elements are further than $\log_2n$ from the root at $i=1$ so you'll need at most $\log n$ swaps for each of the $n$ elements. This, by the way, is not as good as possible: there's different algorithm that builds a heap in no more than a multiple of $n$ time.